# Can my laptop's model have internet speed restrictions?

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, speed, internet-speed

So I just upgraded to 120 Mbps internet. It works fine on all of the devices on the network, I get up to 90-100 on most. However, even connected through an ethernet cable, this specific laptop keeps getting capped at 40 Mbps download speed on speedtest.net. I tried:

- Turning off firewalls
- Checking to see if anything else was consuming data
- Connecting to an ethernet cable. (I get the same speed of about 40 Mbps with and without the cable)
- Checking the speed of my connections in Network connections (I'm using Windows 8.1), the ethernet says 100Mbps, and the WiFi says 72 Mbps.
- Checking for driver updates in the device manager (although I'm not really sure how that stuff works...)

My computer is a 3-4(-ish) year old Presario CQ42 Compaq. Anything I can do?

Comment: The first thing I would suggest trying is removing as many variables as possible and getting at the raw network speed. On *nix, dd and netcat are often useful for that purpose (with crossover cable to another known good system if possible). Not sure how to best do it on Windows. Maybe your laptop's network card advertises 100 Mbit/s capability, but in reality it can't keep up with more than about 40 Mbit/s? Stranger things have happened.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, network cards have speed limitation. As I know the Ethernets developed with supporting speeds of 10, 100 and 1000 Mbit/s.
you can check the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet